# I created a struct in my Visual Studio project, and I need to output it in a richtextbox it says I need to put it into a string but I dont know how

Tags: c#, visual-studio

```
public struct cd
{
    public string naslov;
    public string izvajalec;
    public string zvrst;
    public string zalozba;
    public int letnica;
    public string cena;

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("{0} {1} {2} {3} {4} {5}", naslov, izvajalec, zvrst, zalozba, letnica, Convert.ToInt32(cena));
    }
}
```

This here is the public override string I tried, I am not familiar with it, so I don't know if that is the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set the Text property:

```
YourTextBox.Text = yourStruct.ToString();
```

P.S. It is better to use string interpolation in your code and use Enlgish names

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return $"{naslov} {izvajalec} {zvrst} {zalozba} {letnica} {Convert.ToInt32(cena)}";
}
```